# Looking for a full featured self-hosted file sharing web app

Tags: web-apps, sharing

I'm looking for something like [MediaFire](http://mediafire.com) or [Box.com](http://box.com), but self-hosted. I've tried [Pydio](http://pyd.io) but I find it to be rather clunky, poorly-programmed, and buggy.

Ideally I'd like a self-hosted file sharing solution that:

- Notifies me or logs info about users accessing the links I share with them, such as date and IP address
- Allows them to upload files to me (optional)
- Will allow me to restrict download of files but allow them to be viewed/played (images, MP3s) (note: for the "average joe"; obviously web savvy people will be able to capture via various means) So what this means is, they can play an MP3 in the browser but there is no download link.
- No user authentication needed. Files are obfuscated e.g. `http://fileshare.net/f8EjpA80AAg`

Thanks in advance!